# Showing vector various feature (location) in QGIS layer menu

Tags: qgis

In QGIS (I'm using 3.16), I would like to know how to display, in the layer menu, the many feature/location included in a vector file (KML)

My KML vector includes 15 features (polygons), but navigating between each is complicated. I have to enter the attribute table, select the feature, and right-click Zoom to feature

Is there a  way to show the content of the vector file in the Layers panel in QGIS so it would have a little arrow next to it I can press and display/hide/zoom to each individual features?
I cant seem to find this option anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are looking for, and because it is a new feature it is not in the version you are using, but maybe useful if you can update.

In QGIS 3.26 you can select features from categorized symbols in the Layers panel:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

[Go2NextFeature](https://gitlab.com/tabacco_editrice/go2nextfeature) plugin allows you to pan or zoom to each feature in the layer quickly:

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/go2nextfeature/